# Use pipe without feeding first argument

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

Is the `%>%` pipe operator always feeding the left-hand side (LHS) to the first argument of the right-hand side (RHS)? Even if the first argument is specified again in the RHS call?

Say I want to specify which variable to use in `cor()`:

```
library(magrittr)
iris  %>%
  cor(x=.$Sepal.Length, y=.$Sepal.Width)
```

But this fails, it looks like it call something like `cor(., x=.$Sepal.Length, y=.$Sepal.Width)` ?

I know I could use instead

```
iris  %$%
  cor(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)
```

But wanted to find a solution with `%>%`...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Is the `%>%` pipe operator always feeding the left-hand side (LHS) to the first argument of the right-hand side (RHS)? Even if the first argument is specified again in the RHS call?

No. You’ve noticed the exception yourself: if the right-hand side uses `.`, the first argument of the left-hand side is *not* fed in. You need to pass it manually.

However, this is *not* happening in your case because you’re not using `.` by itself, you’re using it inside an expression. To avoid the left-hand side being fed as the first argument, you additionally need to use braces:

```
iris %>% {cor(x = .$Sepal.Length, y = .$Sepal.Width)}
```

Or:

```
iris %$% cor(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)
```

— after all, that’s what `%$%` is there for, as opposed to `%>%`.

But compare:

```
iris %>% lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length, data = .)
```

Here, we’re passing the left-hand side expression explicitly as the `data` argument to `lm`. By doing so, we prevent it being passed as the first argument to `lm`.

Comment: Great! I was missing the brace, thanks for the explanation! and sorry for the typo mentioning initially %$% when I meant %>% !

Answer (score 3):

One can use an anonymous function

**`magrittr` pipe**

```r
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
  (\(.) cor(x = .$Sepal.Length, y = .$Sepal.Width))
# [1] -0.1175698
```

**`base` pipe**

```r
iris |>
 (\(.) cor(x = .$Sepal.Length, y = .$Sepal.Width))() # Note the extra parentheses
# [1] -0.1175698
```

Answer (score 0):

please check [pipeR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pipeR) package. This packages defines `%>>%` operator so that you can inpute your lhs object as `.` argument in the rhs function.

For example, suppose `lst` is a list of matrix, and you want to `cbind` all of them. You can do this: `lst %>>% {do.call(cbind, .)}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).